# Kotlin - Unable to check interface usage using `is`

Tags: kotlin

I'm working in Kotlin and getting a class like such:

```
val payloadClass =  try {
    Class.forName("com.something.SomeClass")
} catch (e: ClassNotFoundException) {
   null
}
```

It's successfully finding the class however when I then go to check whether it implements some interface, it keeps returning `false`:

To check I'm using the keyword `is`:

so `payloadClass is AGreatInterface`.

Is there some reason why this wouldn't work. I've used `is` elsewhere and it works as expected, wondering if it's something to do with `Class.forName`.

I used `payloadClass.interfaces.contains(AGreatInterface::class.java)` and that worked. But why wouldn't `is` work?

Any ideas appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: use `(AGreatInterface::class.java).isAssignableFrom(payloadClass)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that `payloadClass` is not a `AGreatInterface`, but  a `java.lang.Class` instance.

If you would create an instance of the class object represented by `payloadClass`, let's say `payloadInstance`, then the `payloadInstance is AGreatInterface` test would succeed.

Comment: Ok got it - so `is` can check of a class uses a specific interface, but only in the case its an actual instance of?

Comment: Correct. It checks whether an instance's type implements or extends a class or interface.